# MongoDB mongoid self reference relationship

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am new to mongo/mongoid and I am trying to setup a self referencing relationships on my sites table.

```
# sites model

has_many :child_sites, :class_name => 'Site'
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Site'

#controller

@event = current_site.child_sites.build(params[:site])
```

current_site is a function that returns the current site object.

I get this error -

> undefined method `entries' for #

Comment: Not sure what your specific problem is but this is not a very mongodb friendly schema. Note that "relationships" as a concept do not exist in mongodb so the above would result in a lot of queries (each "relationship" will have to be seperately queried by the driver).

Comment: Thanks for the advise, what is the best way to create a parent site that has a child site ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try changing your relation definitions to the following:

```
has_many :child_sites, :class_name => 'Site', :cyclic => true
belongs_to :parent_site, :class_name => 'Site', :cyclic => true
```

I don't know exactly what it does, but I remember it being discussed in the Mongoid google group. If that doesn't work, you should try to set `inverse_of` on both the relation macros. Most of the time setting `inverse_of` correctly does the job.

```
has_many :child_sites, :class_name => 'Site', :inverse_of => :parent_site
belongs_to :parent_site, :class_name => 'Site', :inverse_of => :child_sites
```

About the extra queries, yes there would be extra queries whenever you want to fetch child_sites of a site or the parent site of a site.

You should consider embedding child sites in parent site, but keep in mind that way you would loose the ability to query child sites in a stand_alone manner. You would always have to access any child site as "parent_site > child_sites".

Also keep in mind the 16MB limit on size of document, which is hard to reach, but might be possible if there are a lot of child sites for a parent and if you are storing template info, like html, css etc. in the document itself.

Comment: has_many :child_sites, :class_name => 'Site', :inverse_of => :parent_site
belongs_to :parent_site, :class_name => 'Site', :inverse_of => :child_sites explains it will and makes it sink in

Answer (score 4):

Cyclic was originally implemented for embedded documents ([see user group entry](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/d17dca475cb5ce47?pli=1)). To make this working on mongoid 2.3 or higher you have to remove the cyclic option:

```
has_many :child_sites, :class_name => 'Site'
belongs_to :parent_site, :class_name => 'Site'
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `recursively_embeds_many` or `recursively_embeds_one`? http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common